# Beginner IOS development - how to get rid of a controller I accidentally added

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

I am not sure what I clicked, but I was making a home screen for my first app on which I am learning, and I added something called the "Root View Controller" How do I get rid of it? I didn't mean to add it.

Also, are controllers here kind of like the code which gets processed after a button is clicked? I have not gotten to that part of the tutorial :)

Thanks![image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on that "Root View Controller" to select it, then press your "*Delete*" key on the keyboard.  That should remove it.

View controllers usually receive actions (i.e. the IBActions that @Fiire referred to... +1 to him!) when you press on a button.  If you didn't set up any actions pointing to the accidentally created root view controller, you should be completely safe to delete the view controller.  And if you did set up actions, you can find them using the object inspector and then "X" (cancel) out any connected actions from buttons or controls to the view controller.

Comment: Thanks now I feel like such a duface :) I was looking for something on the right side of the screen lol...

Comment: I'm glad you were able to figure it out!

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Xcode 4, you can easily delete controls by selecting them on the inspector area on the left. Just click the item to delete and hit backspace.  
Edit: Saw the image now. Just click what you want to delete and hit back space. As simple as that. 
The code that gets processed after clicking (touching actually) is linked through IBActions. You should look those up, since they are a VERY important part of apps. Let's say they are the "event handlers". Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Two points here, just to add to the other answers. First is that Xcode has a lot of levels of undo, so usually control-z can bring you back. But Xcode does crash and then you cannot undo. For this reason, I (like many other devs) use Git obsessively as they work to be able to recover from situations like yours. A test project like this is a perfect place to get your git on... or Mercurial or whatever solution you happen to like.